What article (if any) to use with the word 'subculture'?
According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the word 'subculture' is countable, which means it should be used with an article. However, I often see it used without any. For example:

Much of the available space in this book will therefore be taken up
with a description of the process whereby objects are made to mean and
mean again as ‘style’ in subculture. (Dick Hebdige, Subculture: The
Meaning of Style, p. 3)
Certainly a case could be made that the Amish represent a subculture,
. . . . For decades, subculture has come under intense scrutiny by
social science scholars who claim that the term is too broad, too
biased, or simply out of date. (J. Patrick Williams, Subcultural
Theory: Traditions and Concepts, p. 3)

Moreover, the word 'subculture' modified by a noun is used with the definite article in some publications but not in others. Examples:

In this the punk subculture can be contrasted against the West
Indian styles which had provided the basic models. (Dick Hebdige,
Subculture: The Meaning of Style, p. 65)
DJ and rap skills became key measures of status in hip-hop subculture,
along with a series of other important distinctions. (J. Patrick Williams, Subcultural Theory: Traditions and Concepts, p. 55)

My question is: when, after all, do we use an article with the noun 'subculture', especially when it is modified by another noun?

You yourself cited the term is too broad from at least one source (i.e. unqualified, it's not a very useful term). In all the examples you cite, I think it's reasonable to assume the singular use refers to all subcultures collectively (i.e. - everything that could be identified as a "cultural subdivision" that's not obviously part of mainstream culture). In cases where a specific subculture is adjectivally identified, it's nearly always context-specific or an optional stylistic choice whether to include an article or not. In this [the] punk subculture can be...

One source for your confusion may be that you’re missing a distinction (that perhaps the author(s) could have made more explicit). In “For decades, subculture has come under intense scrutiny by social science scholars who claim that the term is too broad,” the topic is not any particular subcultures, but the word subculture. Check out the use-mention distinction—the difference between London the city and London the six-letter noun.

Another source of confusion is that subculture is sometimes (but not always) synonymous with counterculture. The Amish are a subculture, but they're not really a counterculture, like punk, beatniks, or hippies. Is "hip-hop" truly a subculture? or just a music genre? I dunno.

If you're talking about a particular subculture, you use an article, like the hip-hop subculture of 1980s New York City. If you're talking about multiple subcultures you can use subculture as a mass noun, like hip-hop subculture in general across all countries. Many English nouns can be both countable and uncountable, and dictionaries don't always make this clear.

The Hebdige quote is an outlier here. It already uses some "edgy" uses and constructions—totally intentional, but outside of everyday usage. I had to do a double-take and a bit of thinking to make meaning of "objects are made to mean and mean again." The whole book devotes itself to a specialized take on the word "subculture," treating it as an entity itself. I'm guessing it might lean toward certain shades of meaning, with "sub-" meaning more "counter/underground/alternative" and less focused on "a smaller division into which larger groups may be parsed."

@StuartF I think you should post this as an answer
